# Why do "align-items: flex-start" and "flex-wrap: wrap" mess with my elements?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a box (`div.rack`) in my application with icons.

[image]

Here's the rack style :

```css
.rack {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

*(the rack has a fixed height)*

This is driving me nuts but why are the wrapped icons not all at the top?

Comment: Did you try `align-content: flex-start`?

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Wait that works... I've never seen this flex property before (beside justify-content and align-items), amazing! thanks

Comment: To align items *within their flex lines* use `align-items`. To align the flex lines *within the container* use `align-content`. For a complete explanation see the duplicate.